# Python: Finding if a process has file handle to known file

Tags: python, windows, file, handle, pid

Initial problem: In python and on Windows, i use **win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW** to find files that have changed. I am trying to find out **WHAT PROCESS** modified them/has a handle opened to them. Any of the following will work: PID, Name, Full path, etc.

That's the top-down approach. I've also got half way up from the bottom-up approach using WMI to get a process list. With the process list I found the process I'm looking for and tried to use psutil.open_files() to find what file handles it had opened, but it doesn't return the relevant files I'm looking for. (i.e. WINWORD.EXE doesn't have "asdf.docx" in the list returned)

**How can I find what process has the lock on the file which was found to be modified by ReadDirectoryChangesW?**